# Struts2 plugins - Dojo or jQuery or...?

Tags: jquery, dojo, struts2, plugins

Since Apache Struts has deprecated Dojo plugin from Struts 2.1.x I am thinking to change everything to jQuery. I especially noticed the difference in sizes (170kb vs 19kb - something like that). I had troubles with IE browser with handling dojo scripts, is this happening also with jQuery (when user is working with the application for a long time, script stops running)?

I have a lot of dojo tags in my applications, and I use most of theirs attributes.

Has anyone had any experience doing that? What were the problems? What were the benefits? Downsides?

Does anyone has any better ideas of which plugin to include with Struts2?

Any answer will be great! Thanks.

Comment: IIRC, Struts was shipping with Dojo 0.4.0 until quite recently, which is about 3 years old, so that may be what you're using as your comparison.  Dojo is now on 1.4 beta, and there have been considerable changes wrt architecture, browser compatibility, and stability.  Struts apparently decided to be more flexible and not bundle a toolkit.  Dojo's widget library, Dijit, has a very different set of widgets and function from JQuery's, as well as built-in accessibility and internationalization, so it may depend on your task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has worked fine for me to change the tags from dojo to jquery. In my (small)project only a few attibutes had to be changed.

The biggest problem for me has been that the tree tag doesn´t exist in jquery so I kept the old dojo tags for that part which has generated alot of conflicts between dojo and jquery. So I recommend that you should change ALL tags at once to jquery to avoid strange behavior.

Answer (score 2):

best to use the struts2-jquery plugin found here

code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest jQuery. I had the same problem working on a project the used Dojo, but found it to be so intrusive I switched to jQuery. With jQuery it's a lot easier to use as it only used the standard HTML markup instead of adding it's own tags like Dojo does. I also found a ton more documentation for jQuery then Dojo as well as some good guides on overcoming the IE6 crap we still have to code for. All in all I would highly recommend jQuery over Dojo in any project.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

While migrating to JQuery we can't get same look and feel etc... like in case of autocompleter.  Below are things missing in the default jquery autocomplete:

1. Rows with alternate shades of light and dark gray
2. Matches from starting key only, at present it searches with matching key from whole keyword
3. To show combobox with down error

Answer (score 0):

With dojo Plugin I have massive Problems with AJAX and File Uploads and JavaScript in AJAX Results.

With [Struts2 jQuery Plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/) it works well for me.

Comment: I did not experience any problems with this, but I did used a lot of time to figure everything out... The documentation is very bad for Dojo plugin.

Answer (score 0):

JQuery and Dojo both are competent and very much rich in the functionalities.Both the framework has their own architectural strenghs.

The first stable version of dojo 0.4 came up early and struts included dojo. Later on Jquery came up with lightweight and stable version, which suited better with Struts plugin based architecture. While dojo architecture had its own trajectory from 0.4 to 1.0-> 1.4 and struts2-dojo plugin made deprecated.

Both the Javascript libraries are very well maintained, enhanced and supported by community. It's just jquery which glues well with struts2 at the moment.